# Example of input with focus breaking slide down animation of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a form that is hidden below a text message. When the user toggles an action the text message slides up, and the height of the container is increased to reveal the form.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.animate-height').toggleClass('open');
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
      $('input[type="text"]').last().focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

form input {
  display: block;
}

.animate-height {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1rem;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.animate-height.open {
  height: 4.5rem;
}

.animate-height.open .animate-margin {
  margin-top: -1rem;
}

.animate-margin {
  margin-top: 0;
  transition: margin-top 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<label>
Set Focus
<input type="checkbox" name="setFocus">
</label>

<div class="animate-height">
  <div class="animate-margin">
    WILL SLIDE UP
  </div>
  <div class="animate-form">
    <form>
      <input name="test" type="text">
      <input name="test" type="text">
      <input name="test" type="text">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Problem

The animations of the form sliding down should be identical when "Set Focus" is checked or not checked, but the above example shows that the animation is *correct* only when "Set Focus" is *not checked*.

I do not understand why they are different, and how can I change the CSS so that the form animates consistently with or without focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acually when focused, the element comes into view by scrolling. So you just can force to scroll back to top before toggling your class with `.scrollTop(0)`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
      $('input[type="text"]').last().focus();
    }
    $('.animate-height').scrollTop(0).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

form input {
  display: block;
}

.animate-height {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1rem;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.animate-height.open {
  height: 4.5rem;
}

.animate-height.open .animate-margin {
  margin-top: -1rem;
}

.animate-margin {
  margin-top: 0;
  transition: margin-top 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<label>
Set Focus
<input type="checkbox" name="setFocus">
</label>

<div class="animate-height">
  <div class="animate-margin">
    WILL SLIDE UP
  </div>
  <div class="animate-form">
    <form>
      <input name="test" type="text">
      <input name="test" type="text">
      <input name="test" type="text">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad it was such an easy fix. I thought I might be faced with some kind of security thing with the browser where you can't focus an input that is hidden by overflow.

Comment: You're welcome, there might be some little adjustments so you don't have the same problem with focusing by Tab key, but basically it will be the same method

Answer (score 0):

Add code highlight
$('.animate-height').toggleClass('open');

```js
    $(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.animate-height').toggleClass('open');
    $( "input:first-child" ).trigger( "focus" );
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
      $('input[type="text"]').last().focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

form input {
  display: block;
}

.animate-height {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1rem;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.animate-height.open {
  height: 4.5rem;
}

.animate-height.open .animate-margin {
  margin-top: -1rem;
}

.animate-margin {
  margin-top: 0;
  transition: margin-top 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<label>
Set Focus
<input type="checkbox" name="setFocus">
</label>

<div class="animate-height">
  <div class="animate-margin">
    WILL SLIDE UP
  </div>
  <div class="animate-form">
    <form>
      <input name="test" type="text">
      <input name="test" type="text">
      <input name="test" type="text">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```